# Wait for element to be clickable

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I need to check logout from menu drop down. when i try to locate element i'm getting error Unable to locate element.

i think that there is synchronize problem because when i add browser.sleep(5000); the tests passed but the problem is that its not stable.

`````
    //from homePage.po.ts
    static logOut() {
        const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.waitForAngular();
        const loader = element(by.className('loader-modal-container'));
        browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(loader), 10001);
        browser.waitForAngular();
        browser.driver.findElement((by.id('user-drop-down'))).click();
        (browser.driver.findElement(by.id('log-out'))).click();
        browser.waitForAngular();


      }
    ```
    //login.e2e-spec.ts

    import {LoginPage} from "../pages/login.po";
    import {HomePage} from "../pages/homePage.po";
    import {browser } from 'protractor';


    describe('login page tests', () => {

      beforeEach(function() {
        LoginPage.navigateTo();
      });


     it('successful logout', () => {
        LoginPage.logIn();
        HomePage.logOut();
        expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(LoginPage.loginPageUrl);
      });
    });
    ````
    //component.html 
     <div class="top-bar-menu">
        <div class="top-bar-menu-item" id="user-drop-down"(click)="op1.show($event,opshow)" >
            <div class="user-dropdown" #opshow  >
              <span id="user-dot" class="top-bar-dot dot semi-bold">{{given_name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()}}{{family_name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() }}</span>
              {{ given_name+' '+family_name }}
            </div>
        </div>


     NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="user-drop-down"]"}
        (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
`````

Comment: Tried explicit wait options? Try like this `browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(), 10000)`

Comment: yes i tried it, the same problem.

Comment: So is that `logout` link pops-up only if we click or it'll also be displayed while hovering the mouse on its parent object? In worst case, try to go for Javascript executor.

Comment: click on item in top menu open dropdown with the logout button, logout display only when the dropdown is open

Comment: Then after clicking on top menu, try to click logout button using Javascript executor

Comment: the problem is that it failed when trying to locate the drop down. 
browser.executeScript("document.getElementById('user-drop-down').click()");
is this correct syntax?  because it still fail

Comment: Remove the extra parens you have in your code and post the code where you included the wait for `log-out` to be clickable along with any error messages you received.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.. Javascript executor on log out button...

```
browser.driver.findElement((by.id('user-drop-down'))).click();
browser.waitForAngular();
browser.executeScript("document.getElementById('log-out').click()");
browser.waitForAngular();
```

Comment: not working. 
 - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  - Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 30 seconds
    (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

```
NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="user-drop-down"]"}
        **(Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402** (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT
10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

[image: Chrome driver and browser compatibility]

I suspect that Driver version and chrome version incompatibility could be the reason for your problem. Since chrome driver 2.46 supports v71-73 and you are using v74. We also observed that there are many evident instances of this. I would suggest first make sure that drive and chrome browser compatibility before running any test case.

Comment: I see what you are saying but if that were the case, it would have thrown immediately on driver creation.

Comment: It's not the case that everything won't work..version incompatibility may work for few operation but not for all. That's why they release compatibility docs. As a best practice we should first check compatibility before testing any code

Comment: Sometimes, yes... Chrome 74 is a hard stop though. If you try to use a Chrome 73 driver with Chrome 74 then it will fail at the start as I described.

Comment: I upgrade chrome driver and get the same error :
  - Failed: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="user-drop-down"]"}
    (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.157)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)